# Enumerating over second level NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, nested, nsdictionary, enumeration

Let's say I have an NSDictionary with a nested NSDictionary like this (simplified, I have about 10 nested dictionaries):

```
key1={
  nesteddictionary={
    nestkey1 = "nested value";
    nestedkey2 = "another value";
  }
  nesteddictionary2={
    nestedkey3 = "want this too";
  }
}
key2="awesome"
```

calling `[dictionary allKeys]` only gives me 'key1' and 'key2'. Is there any easy way to loop over all keys inside of a nested dictionary like this? Even the nested ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recursive function

```
- (void) findAllKey:(NSDictionary*)dic
{
    for ( NSString *key in [dic allKeys] )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",key);

        if ( [[dic objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] )
        {
            [self findAllKey:[dic objectForKey:key]];
        }
    }
}
```

it's Depth-First-Search

Comment: Was hoping to avoid recursion, but it appears its necessary. Anyways I'll probably be using a slightly modified version of this (doing work inside call as well, instead of just finding keys) but this answers the question perfectly.

Comment: you can use a Breadth First Search to avoid recursion, it's easy to do